# Spotify search api throws 404 error at random times

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

This behavior feels very wrong to me...

I'm using the spotify api to search for artists and my code is throwing a 404 error if spotify can't find what I'm searching for... but this feels very wrong to me. The whole point of a search endpoint should be to *see* if spotify has the resource, and if they don't, they can just return me an empty list. And often, they *do* return me an empty list if my search has no results. But in the past couple weeks, it will sometimes throw an error exception.

Here's an example.

```
# Just assume this is a spotipy instance that works
spotify = initSpotifyClient()

# The name is a bit strange, but nonetheless, this works correctly
name = 'Blak Twang And Breis And Cons And Creed And Donovan Kingjay And Hill St Soul And Karl Hinds And Navi'
results = spotify.search(name, limit=20, type='artist')
```

In this example, everything works as expected. However, if I do nothing more than add "The " at the beginning of the name that I'm searching then the spotipy client will throw a 404 exception.

For example:

```
# Just assume this is a spotipy instance that works
spotify = initSpotifyClient()

# The only difference is that the name now starts with "The "
name = 'The Blak Twang And Breis And Cons And Creed And Donovan Kingjay And Hill St Soul And Karl Hinds And Navi'
results = spotify.search(name, limit=20, type='artist') # THIS THROWS AN ERROR
```

Shouldn't this just return an empty list rather than throwing a 404 exception? This feels very strange to me.

Comment: What happens if you add "The" at the beginning but remove some from the end? Maybe you are bumping into a character limit.

Comment: Yep I literally just figured that out as soon as I read your message lol

Answer (score 0):

Ok for anyone who found this, the search endpoint has a character limit of 100 characters. If you have any more than that, the endpoint will throw an exception.